# PHP MySQL command syntax error

Tags: php, sql

This sql query is not working:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO top(topic_subject,topic_date, topic_cat, topic_by)
VALUES(" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic_subject']) . " , NOW()," . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic_cat']) . " , " . isset ($_SESSION['user_id']) . ")";
```

how can I fix it?. I am getting this error message.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 2`
```

Comment: 1. You're not quoting your strings. 2. Parameterize your queries.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that topic_subject is character data. To include literal strings in SQL text, it should be enclosed in single quotes.

```
... VALUES ('abc', ...
```

---

If you used prepared statements, this wouldn't be an issue, and for the *love* of *all* things that are *beautiful* and *good* in this world, don't use the deprecated PHP mysql_ interface for new development. It's been superseded by the **mysqli_** and **PDO** interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the quotes.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO top(topic_subject,topic_date, topic_cat, topic_by)
VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic_subject']) . "' , NOW(),'" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic_cat']) . "' , '" . isset ($_SESSION['user_id']) . "')";
```

And be aware that `mysql_*` is deprecated. Use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple problems here.

1. Quote your strings
2. Make sure your data is of the correct type

```
    $topic_subject = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic_subject']);
    $topic_date = NOW();
    $topic_cat = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic_cat']);
    $topic_by = isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ? $_SESSION['user_id'] : ""; // always returns a string value.

    $sql = "INSERT INTO top(topic_subject,topic_date, topic_cat, topic_by) 
    VALUES('{$topic_subject}' , {$right_now}, '{$topic_cat}' , '{$topic_by}')";
```

It may help you to use more variables in your code (shown) so that you can use a debugger to verify that the strings and variables you create have the values you intend them to have.